# Subtotal using awk for multiple columns

Tags: perl, awk, scripting

with out Excel is that possible to do subtotal for multiple columns using awk for a csv file

File1.txt

```
Group,Host,1-Dec-14,2-Dec-14,3-Dec-14,4-Dec-14,5-Dec-14,6-Dec-14
GroupA,HostA,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupB,HostB,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupA,HostC,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupC,HostD,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupB,HostE,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupC,HostF,10,20,30,40,50,60
```

File with departments:

```
Group,Host,Dept,1-Dec-14,2-Dec-14,3-Dec-14,4-Dec-14,5-Dec-14,6-Dec-14
GroupA,HostA,Finance,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupB,HostB,HR,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupA,HostC,Finance,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupC,HostD,HR,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupB,HostE,Finance,10,20,30,40,50,60
GroupC,HostF,HR,10,20,30,40,50,60
```

Result is

```
Group,Host ,1-Dec-14,2-Dec-14,3-Dec-14,4-Dec-14,5-Dec-14,6-Dec-14
GroupA Total,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GroupB Total,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GroupC Total,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GrandTotal,,60,120,180,240,300,360
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. Use an associative array.

Comment: @ Barmar

awk -F, '{a[$1]+=$3;}END{for(i in a)print i", "a[i];}' 

above code performs for 3 rd column , how to do the same for multiple columns , with out specifically mentioning column ref in array and also to exclude header in file

Comment: `NR>1` to skip the first line

Comment: Why is there a `Perl` tag on this question? You have asked only for an `awk` solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for true 2D arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 { print; next }
{
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        subtot[$1][i] += $i
    }
}
END {
    for (group in subtot) {
        printf "%s%s", group, OFS
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, subtot[group][i]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Group,Host,1-Dec-14,2-Dec-14,3-Dec-14,4-Dec-14,5-Dec-14,6-Dec-14
GroupA,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GroupB,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GroupC,,20,40,60,80,100,120
```

Comment: Getting Error 

awk: tst.awk:5:         subtot[$1][i] += $i

awk: tst.awk:5:                   ^ syntax error

awk: tst.awk:12:             printf "%s%s", OFS, subtot[group][i]

awk: tst.awk:12:                                              ^ syntax error

Comment: Then you are not using GNU awk as stated is required (or are using a very old version that didn't support 2D arrays).

Comment: gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.x86_64 is installed in pc , what is version supports above script

Comment: That is a very, very old gawk. Gawk is now on 4.1.1 and true multi-dimensional arrays ("arrays of arrays") and a ton of other useful features have been supported since 4.0, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History.

Answer (score 2):

This program does as you ask. It uses the usual strategy of reading the data into memory in an appropriate form and then printing that data to the output.

As it stands it reads the input from `DATA` and sends the output to `STDOUT`. I trust you know how to open your own input and output files? The output can be saved to any file you like by using a redirecting `>` on the command line, but please say if you need more help.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print scalar <>;  # Copy and ignore the header

my (%data, @groups, @grand);

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($group, $host, @vals) = split /,/;
  push @groups, $group unless $data{$group};
  for my $i (0 .. $#vals) {
    $data{$group}[$i] += $vals[$i];
    $grand[$i] += $vals[$i];
  }
}

for my $group (@groups) {
  print join(',', $group, '', @{ $data{$group} }), "\n";
}

print join(',', 'GrandTotal', '', @grand), "\n";
```

**output**

```
Group,Host,1-Dec-14,2-Dec-14,3-Dec-14,4-Dec-14,5-Dec-14,6-Dec-14
GroupA,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GroupB,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GroupC,,20,40,60,80,100,120
GrandTotal,,60,120,180,240,300,360
```

Comment: ah got it , saved above code as sub and run as perl sub 

but is every time we need to save data in same file containing code ?

Comment: Okay I assumed you would know how to open a file in Perl. I have changed my solution so that it expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line so, assuming you name the program file `group_totals.pl`, you can run it using `group_totals.pl input.csv > totals.csv` which will take the input from `input.csv` and write the output to `totals.csv`

Comment: If i add another column department in 3 rd column , how the code need to be customised , just to understand if i add more column and if i want to subtotal them

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl script that can work as a template:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $fn = 'File1.txt';
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
open(my $fh, '<', $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!\n";
my $header = <$fh>;
my %grp; 
my @tot;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($csv->parse($line)) {
        my @fields = $csv->fields();
        my $key = $fields[0];
        $grp{$key} //= [(0) x ( scalar(@fields) - 2 )];
        for my $i (2..$#fields) {
            $grp{$key}->[$i - 2] += $fields[$i];
            $tot[$i - 2] += $fields[$i];
        }
    } else {
        warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
    }
}
close($fh);

print $header;
for (sort keys %grp) {
    print $_ . " Total,," . join( ",", @{$grp{$_}}) . "\n";
}
print "GrandTotal,," . join( ",", @tot ) . "\n";
```

Comment: There's actually no need for either the `chomp` or the `$grp{$key} //= [(0) x ( scalar(@fields) - 2 )]`. Also, `Text::CSV->error_diag` returns the *field* from the input that is in error, which can be much more useful than the whole line.

Comment: In my solution the `chomp` *is* necessary because I just `split` each line, and without `chomp` the last field would end in a newline. In your case, `Text::CSV` would remove it for you. And you're very welcome.

Comment: saved as subtotal and executed as perl subtotal

but got few errors 

Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC

 (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 



/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at sub line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sub line 4.

Comment: You must install module `Text::CSV`.

Comment: How to intsall it 
Tried 
/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e'install Text::CSV_XS'
 
But still same error

Comment: Probably you installed `Text::CSV_XS` and not `Text::CSV`.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating pipe output using tee + mkfifo. Usefull for **large** files

```
$>cat foo 
foo,10,foo_a
bar,10,bar_a
foo,20,foo_b
bar,20,bar_b
foo,69,foo_c
bar,69,bar_c

$>mkfifo fifotmp

$>awk -F',' ' 
BEGIN {T="\t" }

pass==1 {
    sum_first_col[ $1 ] += $2;
    sum_all += $2;
} 

pass==2 { 
    percentage_itm=100 * $2 / sum_first_col[ $1 ];
    percentage_all=100 * $2 / sum_all;

    print $1 T $2 T $3 T percentage_itm T percentage_all;

}' pass=1 <(cat foo | tee -a fifotmp) pass=2 <(cat fifotmp ) 

OR 

$>cat foo | tee -a fifotmp | awk -F',' ' 
    BEGIN {T="\t" }

    pass==1 {
        sum_first_col[ $1 ] += $2;
        sum_all += $2;
    } 

    pass==2 { 
        percentage_itm=100 * $2 / sum_first_col[ $1 ];
        percentage_all=100 * $2 / sum_all;

        print $1 T $2 T $3 T percentage_itm T percentage_all;

    }' pass=1 - pass=2 <(cat fifotmp ) 

foo 10  foo_a   10.101  5.05051
bar 10  bar_a   10.101  5.05051
foo 20  foo_b   20.202  10.101
bar 20  bar_b   20.202  10.101
foo 69  foo_c   69.697  34.8485
bar 69  bar_c   69.697  34.8485
```