# Rearanging data file in AWK providing subtotals and totals

Tags: awk

I have the following data:

```
cat st_in.txt 
2015-01-01  2   A   FI
2015-02-03  4   B   VI
2015-03-01  6   A   FI
2015-01-08  -4  C   VE
2016-01-05  -3  B   VE
2016-02-03  -1  D   FE
2016-04-01  -2  B   FE
2016-06-13  -5  D   VE
2017-01-01  2   A   VI
2017-02-03  3   A   VI
2017-02-04  8   C   FI
2017-01-05  -1  B   FE
```

I want to output the data in this way (without comments of course):

```
        2015    2016    2017    # ...

A       0       0       5       # $2>0 && $4~/VI/       Ordered alphabetically asc
B       4       0       0       #       .                       .
sumVI   4       0       5

A       8       0       0       # $2>0 && $4~/FI/               .
C       0       0       8       #       .                       .
sumFI   8       0       8

sumI    12      0       13      # sumI=sumFI+sumVI

B       0       -3      0       # $2<0 && $4~/VE/               .
C       -4      0       0       #       .                       .
D       0       -5      0       #       .                       .
sumVE   -4      -8      0

B       0       -2      -1      # $2<0 && $4~/FE/               .
sumFE   0       -2      -1      #       .

sumE    -4      -10     -1      # sumE=sumFE+sumVE

NET     8       -10     12      # NET=sumI+sumE
```

I am new to awk and not sure how to approach this. I have read on gnu.org awk manual about multi-dimensional arrays and arrays of arrays, which I assume I will be needing here but don't fully understand how they work. I am able to do this for one year but not multiple years. Please note that st_in.txt is very large and spans more years than in this sample. Also is there a good resource that you can recommend to learn how to pivot data tables in awk.

This is what I have attempted so far. This however does not work:

```
cat trans1
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN{OFS="\t"
    cat[$3]
    height[$4][$3] +=$2
    width[substr($1,1,4)][$4][$3] +=$2
    }

    END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";
    for (width in height){
        for (cat in height[width]){
            if($2>0 && $4~/VI/)
                {print cat, height[width]}
            else if($2>0 && $4~/FI/)
                {print cat, height[width]}
            else if($2<0 && $4~/VE/)
                {print cat, height[width]}
            else {print cat, height[width]}}}

    }
' "${@:--}"
```

I get the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:11: (FILENAME=st_in.txt FNR=12) fatal: attempt to use array `width' in a scalar context
```

Comment: Have you by chance looked at existing questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587979/subtotal-using-awk-for-multiple-columns)? If so you might consider editing your question and mentioning what you've found when searching and why it won't work in your situation, or something to that effect. Also if you've made any coding attempts you might consider including your code, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry David, I have been very busy. I have put an amended update of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line:

```
width[substr($1,1,4)][$4][$3] +=$2
```

you declare `width` to be an array so you can't use that same name at this line:

```
for (width in height){
```

as a scalar (the index to another array, `height`). Just change that second one to `wid` or some other name to get rid of the error message.  Obviously change `width` to `wid` where used as the index to `height[]` within the loop too.

---

Use this as a starting point, I picked variable names that better represent what they contain (though I've no idea what your 4th column represents so I just named it `box` - change to something meaningful) to try to help you understand what each means throughout your code as the first step to debugging and enhancing it:

```
$ cat trans1
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    {
        year   = substr($1,1,4)
        height = $2
        cat    = $3
        box    = $4

        cats[cat]
        boxCat_2_Heights[box][cat] += height
        yearBoxCat_2_Widths[year][box][cat] += height
    }

    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
        for (box in boxCat_2_Heights) {
            for (cat in boxCat_2_Heights[box]) {
                height = boxCat_2_Heights[box][cat]

                if      (height>0 && box~/VI/) { type = "type1" }
                else if (height>0 && box~/FI/) { type = "type2" }
                else if (height<0 && box~/VE/) { type = "type3" }
                else                           { type = "type4" }

                print box, cat, height, type
            }
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./trans1 st_in.txt
FE      B       -3      type4
FE      D       -1      type4
FI      A       8       type2
FI      C       8       type2
VE      B       -3      type3
VE      C       -4      type3
VE      D       -5      type3
VI      A       5       type1
VI      B       4       type1
```

I'm not saying the above is what you actually want, just that it does what your existing code is attempting to do but using meaningful names and valid syntax. It's a starting point for you.

Comment: I did that but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Did you maybe not change the index name where you use it within the loop too, e.g. `print cat, height[width]` -> `print cat, height[wid]`?

Comment: I have changed all "width" off to "wid" in the END block and still get the same error message.

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error message here as frankly I don't believe it.

Comment: ```awk: cmd. line:11: (FILENAME=st_in.txt FNR=12) fatal: attempt to use array `cat' in a scalar context```

Comment: Surely you can see that that's not the same error message. Your original one was complaining about `width`, this one about `cat`. You're doing the same thing with `cat` that you did with `width`.

Comment: I have changed cat to cat1, height to height1 and width to wid. So now I do not get any error messages. However when I run this now nothing happens.

Comment: Then you should accept an answer to this question you asked about the error message and ask a new, followup question with your modified code about the new problem.

Comment: Wait - you changed `height` to `height1` in your END section? But `height` in your END section was the name of the array - that's what you wanted.

Comment: yes that was what I wanted. But I keep getting these error messages.

Comment: Right, but it's not the same error message each time - you have to read the error message and think about what it says. Put `height1` back to `height` and run your code. What's the new error message (copy/paste it here)?

Comment: all height1s or just the first one?

Comment: If I change the first one in the END block back to height I get:
```awk: cmd. line:11: (FILENAME=st_in.txt FNR=12) fatal: attempt to use a scalar value as array```

Comment: Change all of them. Again, you WANT to use the array named `height` in your code.

Comment: If I change all of them in the END block back to height I get:
```awk: cmd. line:18: (FILENAME=st_in.txt FNR=12) fatal: attempt to use array `height[""]' in a scalar context```

Comment: OK, at `height[$4][$3] +=$2` your defining `height[$4]` to contain **an array** indexed by multiple `$3`s then in your END section at `print cat, height[wid]` you're trying to print the contents of `height[wid]` but as I just mentioned `height[wid]` is an **array** while `print` prints **scalars**. Hence your error message. Figure out what you actually wanted to print there and change the code to do that.

Comment: The other significant problem in your code is you're trying to use $2 and $4 in the END section - $2 is the 2nd field of the current record, there is no current record in an END section as you've finished reading all of the records and the values of $2, $4, etc. are undefined. I'm guessing you probably want to be testing the values of the indices (and/or contents) of the arrays there instead. So, think about and try to fix everything we just discussed and then ask a new question if you need more help.

Comment: Alright, thanks heaps for your help. I will have to do that tomorrow as we are close to midnight.

Comment: I just noticed your first block of code is all inside a BEGIN section so it's not even populating the arrays as the data is read.

Comment: @EdMorton In your `END` block shouldn't it be `if (height>0 && box~/VI/) { type = "type1" }` instead of `if (cat>0 && box~/VI/) { type = "type1" }`? Same for the 2 following lines.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I don't know, I wasn't trying to get the script right, just trying to minimally change the OPs code to show how to use good names, arrays vs scalars, populate the arrays, not use fields numbers in the END section, etc. I'll change it to `height` on  the assumption you've put more thought into it than I have - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not the complete solution but a more structured approach which requires the final formatting...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {SUBSEP=FS} 
             {split($1,f1,"-"); 
              s=substr($4,2); y=f1[1]; 
              a[s,$4,y,$3]=+$2; 
              a[s,$4,y,"sum"$4]+=$2; 
              a[s,"+",y,"sum"s]+=$2;
              a["+","+",y,"NET"]+=$2} 
       END   {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file | 
 sort -k1,2r -k4,4 -k3,3

I VI 2017 A 3
I VI 2015 B 4
I VI 2015 sumVI 4
I VI 2017 sumVI 5
I FI 2015 A 6
I FI 2017 C 8
I FI 2015 sumFI 8
I FI 2017 sumFI 8
I + 2015 sumI 12
I + 2017 sumI 13
E VE 2016 B -3
E VE 2015 C -4
E VE 2016 D -5
E VE 2015 sumVE -4
E VE 2016 sumVE -8
E FE 2016 B -2
E FE 2017 B -1
E FE 2016 D -1
E FE 2016 sumFE -3
E FE 2017 sumFE -1
E + 2015 sumE -4
E + 2016 sumE -11
E + 2017 sumE -1
+ + 2015 NET 8
+ + 2016 NET -11
+ + 2017 NET 12
```

this creates various subtotals based on the keys of the array, at the end it prints the whole array (and subtotals). By carefully choosing the key you can calculate what you need.

`s` is the top level category, `y` is the year.

```
              a[s,$4,y,$3]=+$2;
```

sums up all repeated entries since uses all the fields

```
              a[s,$4,y,"sum"$4]+=$2;
```

groups based on field 4 values (VI,FI, etc.)

```
              a[s,"+",y,"sum"s]+=$2;
```

group based on top level category (I,E)

```
              a["+","+",y,"NET"]+=$2}
```

this sums up everything based on the year. Finally

```
  END   {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}
```

at the end of the file, extract all the entries from the array and print.

```
  sort -k1,2r -k4,4 -k3,3
```

does the sorting based on I/E VI,FI A/B/.. and year.

For example, as an exercise you can add the overall sum easily by dropping or replacing `y` with a constant (I used `+`).

Comment: Thanks karakfa for making the effort. Could you please help me understand how those arrays work a[... ? e.g. s and $4 are they not the same thing? When you loop through k in a is every line of a[s... called for every line in the file? Sorry I am trying to wrap my mind around multidimensional arrays. Your code works but I am not sure how to get a sum column for each year.

Comment: added explanation. Note that sum of each year is there already with the "NET" label. Don't think them as multidimensional arrays if you're not familiar. This of this as saving (key, value) pairs, where key is the unique entry for the subtotals.